# Getting wrong XSOM baseType for a XSSimpleType

Tags: java, xsom

I have a simple xsd

```
<xs:element name="shoesize" type="shoetype"/>
<xs:complexType name="shoetype">
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:integer">
  <xs:attribute name="country" type="attrType" />
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="attrType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="abc" />
    <xs:enumeration value="xyz" />
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I am trying the retrieve base type of the complexType 'shoetype' using the following code

```
void parseComplexType(XSComplexType xsComplexType, StringBuffer stringBuffer) {
    XSContentType xsContentType = xsComplexType.getContentType();
    if (xsContentType != null) {
        XSParticle xsParticle = xsContentType.asParticle();
        if (xsParticle != null) {
            parseParticle(xsParticle, stringBuffer);
        } else if (xsContentType.asSimpleType() != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(parseSimpleType(xsContentType.asSimpleType()));
        }
    } 
    return;
}

String parseSimpleType(XSSimpleType xsSimpleType) {
    if (xsSimpleType.isPrimitive()) {
        return(xsSimpleType.getName());
    } 
    if (xsSimpleType.asRestriction() != null) {
        XSRestrictionSimpleType xsRestrictionSimpleType = xsSimpleType.asRestriction();
        Iterator<XSFacet> facetIterator = xsRestrictionSimpleType.iterateDeclaredFacets();
        if (facetIterator != null) {

            // Special Case
            if (!facetIterator.hasNext()) {
                return xsSimpleType.getBaseType().getName();
            }
            StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            strBuffer.append("[");
            while (facetIterator.hasNext()) {
                XSFacet xsFacet = facetIterator.next();
                if (xsFacet.getName().equals(XSFacet.FACET_ENUMERATION)) {
                    strBuffer.append(xsFacet.getValue() + (facetIterator.hasNext() ? " / " : ""));
                } else if (xsFacet.getName()
                        .equals(XSFacet.FACET_MAXLENGTH)) {
                    strBuffer.append(xsSimpleType.getBaseType().getName());
                    break;
                } else if (xsFacet.getName().equals(
                        XSFacet.FACET_FRACTIONDIGITS)) {
                    strBuffer.append(xsSimpleType.getBaseType().getName());
                    break;
                } else if (xsFacet.getName().equals(
                        XSFacet.FACET_MINEXCLUSIVE)) {
                    strBuffer.append(xsSimpleType.getBaseType().getName());
                    break;
                } else if (xsFacet.getName().equals(
                        XSFacet.FACET_MAXEXCLUSIVE)) {
                    strBuffer.append(xsSimpleType.getBaseType().getName());
                    break;
                } else if (xsFacet.getName().equals(
                        XSFacet.FACET_MININCLUSIVE)) {
                    strBuffer.append(xsSimpleType.getBaseType().getName());
                    break;
                } else if (xsFacet.getName().equals(
                        XSFacet.FACET_MAXINCLUSIVE)) {
                    strBuffer.append(xsSimpleType.getBaseType().getName());
                    break;
                } else if (xsFacet.getName().equals(
                        XSFacet.FACET_LENGTH)) {
                    strBuffer.append(xsSimpleType.getBaseType().getName());
                    break;
                } else if (xsFacet.getName().equals(
                        XSFacet.FACET_WHITESPACE)) {

                    // ignore
                    break;
                } else {

                    // Log this type
                    System.out.println(xsFacet.getName());
                }
            }
            strBuffer.append("]");
            return strBuffer.toString();
        } 
    } if (xsSimpleType.asComplexType() != null) {
        StringBuffer stBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        parseComplexType(xsSimpleType.asComplexType(), stBuffer);
        return stBuffer.toString();
    } 
    return null;
}
```

but I am getting 'decimal' as the baseType name, but its actually an xs:integer. Its getting into 'XSFacet.FACET_MAXLENGTH' else part defined in the method parseSimpleType()??.
How will I get integer as the baseType of the complexType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code walks base type links from xs:integer to xs:decimal; only the latter is primitive. It seems a case of wrong expectations: in XML Schema terminology, not all **built-in** types are actually **primitive**.

See the convenient [diagram in the XML Schema standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes) for further details.